# ASP.NET parser error trying to load page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I keep getting the following error in visual studio when trying to run the page. 
It keeps happening whenever I create a new web form and I don't know why.

If I remove the inherits it then works but my code page then does not recognize any of the buttons on this page etc. So doesn't really solve the problem.

Any ideas on a permanent solution?

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load type
>   'WebApplication1.HolidayRequests'. Source Error:  Line 1:  <%@ Page
>   Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"
>   MasterPageFile="~/HRSite.Master" CodeBehind="HolidayRequests.aspx.vb"
>   Inherits="WebApplication1.HolidayRequests" %>
>
> Source File: /HR/HolidayRequests.aspx    Line: 1

Comment: Two things: 

1) Accept answers to your existing questions or you'll find people will be reluctant to help.
2) Can you please provide a code sample that produces the error you are seeing?

Comment: What namespace/class is in the code-behind?  The page is trying to load a class called `WebApplication1.HolidayRequests` from the code, but that class isn't found.

Comment: <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/HRSite.Master" CodeBehind="HolidayRequests.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.HolidayRequests" %>

Comment: That is the name of the class; its putting it in as a default but not accepting it. All other pages in the same folder are working except fo one being created as of now?

Comment: What is the partial class called in the HolidayRequests.aspx.vb page? have you tried removing `WebApplication1.` from the `Inherits` value? See if this thread is any help http://forums.asp.net/t/1318456.aspx/1

Comment: I just tried to remove the WebApplication1. but its still happening. Apologies for my ignorance but i don't know what a partial class is?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/HRSite.Master" CodeBehind="HolidayRequests.aspx.vb" Inherits="HolidayRequests" %>
```